# rails 4, globalize gem, how to setting default locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n, globalize

I'm using the globalize gem to support multiple locales.

config/locales directory have three file

```
en.yml,  ja.yml, ch-HK.yml
```

and my routing file is

```
....
root :to => 'main#index', :locale => :en
 scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
   namespace(:api){ resources :badges }
   namespace(:api){
     resources :events do
       get :list, :on => :collection
     end 
   }   
end 
....
```

my root path (/) is setting default locales

but I don't know how to setting default locales in api_controller

I wanna

```
/api/events.json ->> /en/api/event.json
/ja/api/events.json ->> /ja/api/events.json
```

is it not accept in rails Project?

must add /:locales/api~~ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every request is passed through a controller and that's the place for setting default locale. All you need to do is to set `I18n.locale = :locale`. There are various methods of detecting user locale, i.e. request header, user preferred language (if logged and stored). You can also check for request format (in case of API) and set locale accordingly. Setting locale for url is not necessary here.

Here's a piece of code I'm using for setting locale:

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  if defined?(params) && params[:locale]
    I18n.locale = params[:locale]
  elsif current_user && current_user.language_id.present?
    I18n.locale = current_user.language.code
  elsif defined?(request)
    I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
  end
  I18n.locale ||= I18n.default_locale
  I18n.locale = :en unless valid_languages.include?(I18n.locale.to_sym)
end
```